# Toolbar buttons for every scene

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having trouble having my toolbar buttons appear in every scene in my project. I have a navigation controller as the initial controller, with the tool bar option selected. I added toolbar buttons to the nav controller, but they do not appear in any scenes.  I have a lot of scenes, and I want the same 4 toolbar buttons to appear in every scene. Any ways to do this? I would prefer a non-programmatic way if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the toolbar buttons to the `toolbarItem` of every individual view controller that will be this navigation controller's child. You can configure this in the storyboard if you wish.

Comment: So there is no way to do it one time and have it displayed for every view controller?

Comment: There is programatically =P

Comment: Would you mind giving me one example that I may use? I'm using a .png file for one button